# (\d+,\d+) add so it is imuneto white spaces

Tags: javascript, regex

How in javascript to make regex to recognize and extract integer numbers for coordinates which have format like

```
( number1, number2 )
```

between `(` and `number1` and `,` and `number2` and `)` can be arbitrary number of whitespaces (user are going to enter coordinates so I don't want to force strict format without whitespaces)

```
(\d+,\d+)
```

what to add to this so it works ?

Comment: You might want to give more information about the data or sample input and expected output

Answer (score 1):

There are a few choices, pending your actual input.

To match all "whitespace characters" (space, tab, carriage return, newline and form feed), you can use the `\s` shorthand approach. If you want a number, in this case `\d+`, to be surrounded by "0 or more" of these, you would use:

```
\s*\d+\s*
```

In your full pattern:

```
\(                  # opening parentheses
    \s*\d+\s*,      # first number followed by a comma
    \s*\d+\s*       # second number
\)                  # closing parentheses
```

Note: The parentheses are escaped here as they're special characters in a regular expression pattern.

Now, if you don't want to match "all whitespace" and were only interested in plain spaces, for example, you could use a matching character set of `[ ]` (i.e. a space between two brackets). In the pattern from above:

```
\(
    [ ]*\d+[ ]*,
    [ ]*\d+[ ]*
\)
```

Not really sure how you want to use the matches, I'm assuming you want the numbers returned individually so in that case, you can use the following:

```
var str = '(1, 2)';
var matches = str.match(/\(\s*(\d+)\s*,\s*(\d+)\s*\)/);
if (matches) {
    var firstNumber = matches[1];
    var secondNumber = matches[2];
    // do stuffs
}
```

Note: In the pattern I used here, I've wrapped the `\d+`s in parentheses; this will "capture" those values in to groups which are then accessible by their "group index". So, the first `(\d+)` will be available in `matches[1]` and the second will be available in `matches[2]`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this regex: `\(\s*\d+\s*,\s*\d+\s*\)`.

<kbd>**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xvwAL/)**</kbd>

Comment: Please it would add more value to your answer if you explained your regex.